# Local Maxima of a function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis

This was a question I was doing recently, however am unsure if my solution is correct. Any help would be great!

**The question**
A function $f$ is said to attain a local maximum at $c ∈ \mathbb{R}$ if there is some $\epsilon > 0$ such
that $f(c) > f(x)$ whenever $|x − c| < \epsilon$.

Suppose that $f : \mathbb{R} → \mathbb{R}$ is twice differentiable, and that $f''(x) < 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Show that there is at most one $c \in \mathbb{R}$ at which f attains
a local maximum

**My Attempt**
Since $f''(x)<0$ for all x, then $f'(x)$ is a monotonically decreasing function. Thus either $f'(x)<0 (\text{ or} >0) , \forall  x\in \mathbb{R}$ in which case we are done (no local maxima), or $\exists a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(a)>0 \text{ and }f(b)<0 $. Thus by Intermediate value theorem in the interval $[a,b]$, we have a $c$ such that $f'(c)=0$.

Now, it is sufficient to show that for this $c$, $f$ attains local maxima.

- $x<c$ : By Mean Value theorem on $[x,c]$, we have that there exists a $b \in (x,c)$ such that $$f(c)-f(x)=f'(b)(c-x)>0$$ as $b<c$ and $f'(x)$ monotonically decreasing and $f'(c)=0$
- $x>c$ : Similar to above, we have that $$f(c)>=f(x)$$

However, I suspect there is a problem with this argument, as this implies that at $c$, f in fact attains a global maxima. 
(reason I suspect this might be wrong: In one of the later parts of this same exercise, the question asked that if, for all x, $f'(x)<K$ where $K<0$ then  $f$ attains global maxima. And then asked if $f$ has second derivative always $<0$, does that mean that it attains global maxima?

Comment: The problem really boils down to showing that a differentiable function only has a local maximum at places where the derivative is 0 and it switches from + to -, as you've noted.  I think your proof of that is a bit sketchy

Comment: Your definition of local max is not quite right since you allow $x=c.$